# samba share linux to windows

Tags: linux, samba

Is it possible to map a linux directory in windows? And can someone please show me how this is done with minimal configuration? I don't need many bells and/or whistles... or even security as the host is a sandbox that is rebuild nightly.

Thank

Comment: What specifically have you tried?  What errors do you see?  Yes, it is absolutely possible, the 100s of pages of people doing it is a form of proof - I have a bunch of samba shares at work from RH.  [Ubuntu Docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide).  In my experience, the most commonly missed step is forgetting to add/enable the local user name to the samba group.  Add: `sudo  smbpasswd -a username`; Enable: `sudo smbpasswd -e username` and then restart the samba service.

Comment: Basically... I have about 20 windows users that need to map "Z" driver (or whatever) to "/var/www" on a linux box that is sort of a sand box. Every single samba config I have tried has failed (and I have tried a lot). The normal failure is windows refusing the user's password, and then reporting not being able to find the server... just not sure what else to try.

Comment: [Proof,](http://i.imgur.com/bDlhZyl.png) just to do away with the stupid part of the question.

Comment: If you don't care about security, tell samba to allow read/write guest access and you won't need to worry about usernames. Also consider installing `webmin` on the Linux host which will allow you to configure all this through a web interface.

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask, is this because you have a linux storage server that you need to add to your windows machines?
If so, I can higly recommend the software called FreeNAS - it's free and has a very easy to use GUI to map drives to windows machines etc.

Just a suggestion.